# Find minimum and maximum dates based on column

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a list with multiple Tasks, each Task is grouped in a Category. Every Task also has a Task Start and Task End Date.

I would like to make a calculated column for the Category Start and Category End Date. So when others add a new task to a category, the dates of the category gets updated.

For example:
[image: Example]

So the Task Start Date is the minimum date of all the start dates

Is this possible using calculated columns and what syntax should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure. You want "Category start date" column should be like this 
if(Category=="Budget")
    Category Start date=Task Start date + 1
else if (Category=="Event")
    Category End Date = Task End Date + 2

You can use below calculated column code for start date and same for end date
=IF(Category="Budget",[Start Date]+1,IF(Category="Event",[Start Date]+1))

Comment: No I want the Category Start Date to be the same for all rows in that category. So for example with Budget something like Min([Task Start Date]) for all rows where [Category]="Budget"